# An exact sequence of Chow groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^n$, with canonical line bundle $O(1)$,let $V\subset \mathbb{A}^{n+1}$ be the affine cone over $X$. How to show there is an exact sequence $A_kX\xrightarrow{c_1(O(1))\cap-}A_{k-1}X\to A_k(V)\to 0$? (Funton Intersection Theory Example 2.6.3(b))

(Here I think $A_K(V)$ is identified with $A_k(V-0)$ and the last map is induced by projection, thus surjective as affine bundle)